# Eclipse neon toolbar appeared randomly

Tags: eclipse

recently when I launched eclipse, I had a toolbar added. I want to get rid of it.... It starts with the hammer up to the "local" part. How to get rid of it ?Here is a screen:
[image]

Comment: Goto Preferences -> Launch Configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the Eclipse [LaunchBar](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/LaunchBar). It used to be packaged as a plugin for Eclipse CDT, but it can now be installed separately from any Eclipse version.

To disable it, go to *Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Launch Bar*. Unselect the box next to *Enable the Launch Bar*.

[image: Launch Bar]